# mysql complicated if/else scenerio

Tags: mysql, case

I have a telephones database `table` with 4 columns:

- `countrycode`
- `areacode`
- `phonenumber`
- `extension`

I'm following the "Canonical" formatting, since I have some international numbers to consider.

And as fate would have it, some numbers entered have extensions.

I have a query that I use to auto-format everything, except the extension:

```
SELECT CONCAT('+',`countrycode`,'(',`areacode`,')', `phonenumber`) AS `fullnumber` ...
```

result:  +1(123)4567890  or:  +61(08)1234 1234
This works great, and it works perfectly with some dialer software I export to.

However, I now need to include the extension in this query.  However, I need to auto-format it like so:

+1(123)4567890 x123

That's rather easy, but since most numbers do not have an extension, I need to make a condition that will include the char (x).  And this is my dilemma, since I'm still learning conditional statements in a query.

Anybody work with weird if/else statements inside a CONCAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `IF` statement works like this:

`IF(condition, iftrue, iffalse)`: If the given condition is true, return the `iftrue` parameter. Otherwise, return the `iffalse` parameter.

So, your query could look something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('+',`countrycode`,'(',`areacode`,')', `phonenumber`, IF(`extension` IS NULL, "", CONCAT(" x", `extension`))) AS `fullnumber ...
```

The MySQL `IF` function is one of several control flow functions. For more information on those functions, see the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: Nice, I originally tried the IF(), and I can see where my formatting was off.  thanks Zach!